# Forgetful functor $Z(C)\rightarrow C$ has Left Adjoint

Tags: limits, category-theory, tensor-products, adjoint-functors, monoidal-categories

The monoidal center $Z(C)$ of a monoidal category $C$ comes with a forgetful functor $F:Z(C)\rightarrow C$ defined $Z(X,\phi)=X.$ Does $F$ always admit a left adjoint? [This is known](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271593/1-s2.0-S0022404917X00054/1-s2.0-S0022404916302456/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEDkaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIE8Jey%2BflKtwk6vYy6vPklknlcqptUcFbDb8lXplqD2zAiBI%2BYSGuj3idpCFTG8ckb0L5%2BPQLXSt1ybbPs%2BGcmw%2BJCqyBQgSEAUaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMSXqfr0x8EW6yphiqKo8FgkRh9t73S8UDlh5uJ6qiJq%2F5c%2F5GOcypOEwDboVIsirHdYyHl3uuXTwAQYM%2FoSmsm9A%2F6FZpAOIBhT5Q%2FOmsZOcWaxsAUGDf3orxI2kKD6P6Zwj54izzddM%2Bhnb5b3qyfVGu2IKUNnyKIYy1jeu13ixccdFAdduEFnJwnLPiRQG6EAh0za1qrjWu%2FitYNDZ3Wp1ecA%2FfQa3jmQKOwWsQ4SQiJc5YyMsAn6c5BCKJoCmodZN8%2BdVYEV3sUazCEtUu8c8RZKMw%2BZhceuZzS2YqPEQCL7zF09s47bOQJjBop3BEO7EzHh4cqNzBq0x4bM74rfE%2Fux471neoKo0kqOO5EWUKS0FCdnSwR43lo5wSeIq%2BcJFECUYZyeyZRSYzkPOEIY3%2F8bfAvrr8GHxGBtTLj2ntq2jP1kGM%2B5oJR0YclhwmaV%2BDXCfIwIvYwSr2RdR80ieljN4gpeKPwEKnZIU4s%2BlJq3jH5JMTgI6HLveWUZiw1k5nuwxON3%2FlgSI0t9Fl%2BFnwj8Bdi%2F%2Fchz4t622ih6%2BNGWHcNPXmyk2VpOfHZfEsrT0GjPcGqZeF4v6IcTFm2vwmH%2FsWYTgzy7Dy2pnMJSiLaezAYKCRQVSC%2FdqqfTTu1gnjrq4TVMWTuLWpNIlP0gViBDFAcSKOrhtrjUO6rxdz1VOLYLrwqUWaLiLDl8fzXDKSisngh7Uvz%2BYFxt4wYbPYBJHwxHszMcJLeID2CoPeuogCPR3qJo0xGIaE61k8sU%2BNCCUry%2FjjwE%2BupS65372dIz9Rp2kPeLv%2FeroyEfGJink68JVqhUy5vYDFOkbQaZvbyUjmHPbbj1A6XdHfy68fsuw0qtdmT7OvbQmTJUF0JuBRY8RD7lN0Iu4hXDC4x5euBjqyARPeco%2Fw96Xleunb9g0Inp2tKN3WIwtHchBVA6G8NXz18cKX%2F0%2BAM2J9hN9r3V5j9IB7BU8ayFbU4Q8IkRhtmp7%2BprWFKLMZkgpOu1384z9dhtk%2B%2BhwP2dv0Kzxln5k9fMVmuVShVV2Nq7Wz1kjIPg9nB5EcQDtlVOSru8KDFrRpdljkQ1W%2BVUADNgojV7D1OszKclOcyjp8nsCAPaCXeUxec%2Bk6UZXkQkDqbAiuJpWSEsc%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20240209T101606Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY7BRWWOAY%2F20240209%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=77d4272beb41fcc6491dac66ce716d0a6b55a694ec29523573b3d9546d06ef2b&hash=4290949a18af25f5da9f4) (Section 3.2.) if $C$ is a tensor category. What about the general case? Tried the General Adjoint Functor Theorem but I'm not even sure if $F$ preserves limits in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a nontrivial monoid $M$ with trivial center (in the sense of monoid theory, i.e. the only element of $M$ commuting with all elements of $M$ is $1\in M$). We can consider $M$ as a monoidal category $(\mathcal{M},\otimes)$ in which $\mathcal{M}$ is the discrete category on the elements of $M$, and $\otimes$ is the monoid operation of $M$. Now, since $\mathcal{M}$ only has identity morphisms and $M$ has a trivial center, the center of $(\mathcal{M},\otimes)$ is the trivial category $*$, so $F\colon *\to\mathcal{M}$ is the inclusion of the object $1$. This is a right adjoint functor iff $1$ is a terminal object of $\mathcal{M}$. Since $\mathcal{M}$ has more than one element and is discrete, this cannot be.